# Getting "File Not Found" error with Jenkins pipeline "Content Replace" plug-in even though the file exists

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying out Jenkins pipeline for the first time and can't seem to figure out what is going wrong here. I checked out the source code from Subversion and then intend to replace file content within one of the checked out file.

I am getting the following error (using Windows Jenkins slave)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'D:\JenkinsRoot\workspace\TestJob2\lib\database.cfg' does not exist

I can see that the file exists on the slave.

Here is a sample code,

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'mynode' }
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
                additionalCredentials: [[...]], 
                excludedCommitMessages: '', 
                excludedRegions: '', 
                excludedRevprop: '', 
                excludedUsers: '', 
                filterChangelog: false, 
                ignoreDirPropChanges: false, 
                includedRegions: '', 
                locations: [[
                    credentialsId: '...', 
                    depthOption: 'infinity', 
                    ignoreExternalsOption: true, 
                    local: '.', 
                    remote: '...']], 
                workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])
            sleep 5
            contentReplace(configs: [
                fileContentReplaceConfig(
                    configs: [
                        fileContentReplaceItemConfig(
                            matchCount: 1, 
                            replace: 'PSTG_USER=${PSTG_USER}', 
                            search: '^PSTG_USER=.*')], 
                        fileEncoding: 'UTF-8', 
                        filePath: 'lib/database.cfg')
        }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above execution the checkout is happening properly and I added sleep just to ensure I am not updating the file too early. However, still I am getting file not found error. Any pointers?

The file exists as using the below command on the windows slave,

```
D:\>dir D:\JenkinsRoot\workspace\TestJob2\lib\database.cfg
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3268-CE51

 Directory of D:\JenkinsRoot\workspace\TestJob2\lib

02/04/2019  06:24 AM               175 database.cfg
               1 File(s)            175 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  101,310,660,608 bytes free
```

Comment: Did you try absolute path? Like `filePath: "${env.WORKSPACE}/lib/database.cfg"`

Comment: Or maybe, as it seems to be Windows node, how about `filePath: 'lib\\database.cfg'`?

Comment: Yet another idea: How about if you wrap your `contentReplace` method with `dir('lib'){ ... }` and try with `filePath: 'database.cfg'``?

Comment: Out of curiosity I created a dummy database.cfg file in the same path on the master node (e.g. slave's `env.WORKSPACE + 'lib/database.cfg'`) and the above contentReplace step is actually successfully accessing the file on master. Am I missing any step above to execute the step on slave? I can see that the first checkout step is happening on slave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code worked for me,

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                node('mynode'){
                    checkout(...)
                    script {
                        String out = readFile('lib/database.cfg').trim()
                        //This prints the original text
                        print out
                        out = out.replaceFirst(/DB_USER=.*/, "DB_USER=$DB_USER")
                        //This prints the replaced text
                        print out
                        writeFile(file: 'lib/database2.cfg', text: out, encoding: 'UTF-8')
                    }
                    //This prints the replaced text from the file
                    bat "type lib\\database2.cfg"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```